# converting lambda expressions to JAVA 7

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-7

I would like to utilize the tools given from this [site](https://objectpartners.com/2016/02/16/automatically-junit-test-dto-and-transfer-objects/) that essentially is able to take simple POJO classes, and output a generated junit tests. However, the code uses Java 8 (needs to be in java 7). What is the Java 7 equivalent to the following piece of code? It is mainly the lambda expressions that needs to be converted.

code:

public abstract class DtoTest {

```
/** A map of default mappers for common objects. */
private static final ImmutableMap<Class<?>, Supplier<t>> DEFAULT_MAPPERS;

static {
    final Builder<Class<?>, Supplier<?>> mapperBuilder = ImmutableMap.builder();

    /* Primitives */
    mapperBuilder.put(int.class, () -> 0);
    mapperBuilder.put(double.class, () -> 0.0d);
    mapperBuilder.put(float.class, () -> 0.0f);
    mapperBuilder.put(long.class, () -> 0l);
    mapperBuilder.put(boolean.class, () -> true);
    mapperBuilder.put(short.class, () -> (short) 0);
    mapperBuilder.put(byte.class, () -> (byte) 0);
    mapperBuilder.put(char.class, () -> (char) 0);

    mapperBuilder.put(Integer.class, () -> Integer.valueOf(0));
    mapperBuilder.put(Double.class, () -> Double.valueOf(0.0));
    mapperBuilder.put(Float.class, () -> Float.valueOf(0.0f));
    mapperBuilder.put(Long.class, () -> Long.valueOf(0));
    mapperBuilder.put(Boolean.class, () -> Boolean.TRUE);
    mapperBuilder.put(Short.class, () -> Short.valueOf((short) 0));
    mapperBuilder.put(Byte.class, () -> Byte.valueOf((byte) 0));
    mapperBuilder.put(Character.class, () -> Character.valueOf((char) 0));

    mapperBuilder.put(BigDecimal.class, () -> BigDecimal.ONE);
    mapperBuilder.put(Date.class, () -> new Date());

    /* Collection Types. */
    mapperBuilder.put(Set.class, () -> Collections.emptySet());
    mapperBuilder.put(SortedSet.class, () -> Collections.emptySortedSet());
    mapperBuilder.put(List.class, () -> Collections.emptyList());
    mapperBuilder.put(Map.class, () -> Collections.emptyMap());
    mapperBuilder.put(SortedMap.class, () -> Collections.emptySortedMap());

    DEFAULT_MAPPERS = mapperBuilder.build();
}
```

Comment: Note that even though you may be restricted to run the deployed code with a given Java version you can use a newer version for testing during builds.  This is easy with Maven if you move your tests to a separate module.

Comment: You would have to define an interface of your own as well to replace `Supplier<?>` in that case!

Comment: @nullpointer or simply drop the `Supplier` completely. A simple map from `Class` to actual (immutable) `Object` would do as well. You only have to remove `Date` as it is not immutable, but since the  code using the map uses the default constructor for all types not contained in the map, there is no reason for `Date` to be here anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using IntelliJ you can use expand the expressions.
Alt + Enter -> Expand lambda